# How to remove extra row in drill down report in SSRS while exporting in to excel?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS to create report. I have created one drilldown report using matrix. it is having row groups and one column group in matrix. when i am running the report in SSDT there is not extra row is showing in grouping.

**SSDT Design and Report Output:**

[image: SSDT Design and Report Output]

Same report when i am exporting into Excel it is showing some extra row on each row group (Highlighted in Yellow).

**Excel Output**

[image: Excel Output]

I have tried with all possible grouping steps, but not able to hide these extra rows in Excel export.

Can anybody help me to fix this.

Comment: when you add groups to your matrix do you add group heather and group footer alone with it? also can you show SSDT design view of the report.

Comment: Yes sir I have used group header for each group, as i want this all row group in single row, so I deleted the header row (i.e. extra row) of all group.